# How can I enable/switch to the internet based keyboard instead of the traditional keyboard?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keyboard

How can I enable/switch to the internet based keyboard instead of the traditional keyboard? I'm trying to display the one which includes the little .com button when the keyboard is displayed after the user clicks a text field.

Thanks in advance!

Amani Swann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It a property of the editText object. You need to set the Input Type, documentation about the Input Type is [found here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html).

You can set the input type either in your layout XML by

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:inputType="textUri"
```

OR

You can set using setInputType method for editText

Comment: I have a strange issue going on... I updated the layout xml with the following:

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:lines="1"
        android:hint="@string/code_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
  android:inputType="textUri" />

But it's still not working. Even when I copy the src from: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-edittexts-inputtype-to-control.html


I still have no .com button when they keyboard is triggered.

Comment: Are you trying on Emulator or device. Some of the devices / emulator do not support..

Comment: That was it... It runs perfectly on an emulator. Thanks!